# Use a completableFuture inside a Synchronous context

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I have to use the next code in a synchronous context and I would like to know wheather it is possible without using `.get()`, which is blocking. I have to get this list in a synchronous code, something like:

```
CompletableFuture<List<SalonDTO>> rooms = roomService.listAll();
```

How can I use this list in the synchronous code to manipulate this data without using `.get()`?

It is possible or recommendable?

```
public CompletableFuture<List<SalonDTO>> listAll() {
        return SalonRepository.findAllAsync(DEFAULT_AGGREGATOR_ID)
                .thenApply(SalonList -> ObjectMapperUtils.mapAll(SalonList, SalonDTO.class))
                .thenApply(SalonList -> {
                    Collections.sort(SalonList, Comparator.comparingInt(SalonDTO::getMinAge));
                    return SalonList;
                });
 }
```

Comment: You can use [`CompletableFuture#join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()), which blocks like `get()` but doesn't throw checked exceptions. Another difference is the thread blocked in a call to `join()` cannot be interrupted.

Comment: @Slaw But I don't want to block, it is possible to achieve this?

Comment: If you want to use the result synchronously then you have to wait for the result. Otherwise, how are you supposed to use a result you don't have yet?

Comment: @Slaw I have a restriction to use blocking code, so do you mean it is not possible? I  must to block this code? I think the same but it is for a restriction.

Comment: @Slaw I have to store the result of this async code in a list inside a sync code and work with this result. I understand that maybe it is not possible to achieve.

Comment: Synchronous means blocking until the result is available. These terms are interchangeable. You can’t have one without the other, as there is no other. Both are just describing the same thing.